# Setting Date and Time in TCP/IP Stack Microchip

Tags: javascript, tcp, stack, microchip

What is the best way to set the date and time to the real time clock (RTCC)?  Can you pull a current time based on the location of your IP address or do you have to set it manually.  If you set it manually what is the best way to have your user set it?  I currently have a simple form using names, is there a better method?

Comment: Do you mean local or UTC time?

Comment: I want local time, can you use UTC?  It works using a basic form, but to have to have the user configure it seems like an extra step for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly, then the best way to find out local time is to serve a web page that reads the local time from the user's browser.

If you only need to find out UTC then it may be possible to do NTP with one of the pool servers, thus avoiding user interaction.

Comment: Good point, i was over thinking it.  I am new to TCP/IP Stack and its very different from my normal web development.  If i just use javascript to pull it into a variable, it should read it from there OS right?  then when its stored in the variable, i should be able to apply it where necessary, such as RTCC.  Does this sound correct?

Comment: You would have to use AJAX to send the value back to the device.